# Why is notification list correct and notifications list not?

Tags: grammar

Are they both correct?

I was thinking that the notifications list is correct because it's a "list of notifications". However, someone mentioned that the correct usage is notification list but he was not able to explain why aside from "It sounds more right"

Thanks

Comment: Related if not actually a duplicate: [Special or specials](/q/96316).

Comment: With new(ish) pairings, the singular-form attributive is almost always the default choice. For a time, the plural-form attributive may co-exist, but these usually die out.  Usually (sports coat / club / car; systems analyst; dogs home; working mens club .... [The dropping of apostrophes will often exercise traditionalists, too.])

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The link you posted + further research helped me find the answer.

Thanks